# Getting values from nested object with C#

Tags: c#

I have this object and I am trying to get the lat and lon values in the location field within telemetry. I am new to c#, but know python. What I would have done in python was:

```
item.details["telemetry"].location.lat
```

Can someone please show me how this is supposed to be done in c#?

```
"details": {
            "asset": {
                "id": "5ca12266-35fe-4f75-8593-588fba777d6d",
                "name": "ZS-FOO"
            },
            "assetType": {
                "id": "87bc0a83-045d-4810-888c-237b5ef17ea4",
                "name": "FOO"
            },
            "telemetry": {
                "flags": 0,
                "ownerId": "4adc68e4-7113-4b0f-8aba-dea213e8a948",
                "originId": "09e0021f-9c54-425b-ae23-cbfe3c786a66",
                "type": "telemetry",
                "linked": ["5ca12266-35fe-4f75-8593-588fba777d6d"],
                "date": "2017/01/20 13:46:01",
                "received": "2017/01/20 13:46:21",
                "active": true,
                "location": {
                    "lon": 116072,
                    "lat": -87448,
                    "speed": 74,
                    "altitude": 98.228,
                    "heading": 56,
                    "accuracy": 5,
                    "age": 0
                },
                "zones": [],
                "routes": null,
                "state": null,
                "telemetry": {
                    "msg_type": 0,
                    "vert_speed": 1.2,
                    "hdop": 1.65,
                    "vdop": 3.51,
                    "movement": 1,
                    "odo_counter": 162704.12317,
                    "hours_00_counter": 1027.885442,
                    "idle_counter": 0
                },
                "io": null,
                "spd": null,
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you've shown here appears to be a json representation, which is not a natively supported data structure in C#.  Can you provide details on the C# data structure into which this would be deserialized?

Comment: You'd want to use a JSON parser to parse the JSON into a dictionary or an object.

Comment: that came form this/: Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));

Comment: Download Newtonsoft.Json dll to help you pares the jsons data.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620173/1638261

Comment: It should be `item.details.telemetry.location.lat`,depending on the names in your classes

Comment: Trying this: var telemetry = JObject.Parse(item.details["telemetry"]); But cannot convert object to string. But if it was an object, why cant iI do item.detials.telemetry? /Users/hermanstander/Projects/IndigoSAT/IndigoSAT/Program.cs(40,40): Error CS1061: Type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' does not contain a definition for `telemetry' and no extension method `telemetry' of type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061) (IndigoSAT)

Comment: First,we must now what is your data origin. Is it Json? or you have an object and,for unknown reasons, you are mixing Json with all this?

Comment: Data in this scenario is Core.Streaming.ServerQueueMessage

Comment: This worked: var telemetry = JObject.Parse(item.details["telemetry"].ToString());
       lat = telemetry["location"]["lat"],

Answer (score 0):

As i said in comment download Newtonsoft.Json

```
JObject data= JObject.Parse(data);
JToken details = data["details"];

string lat = details["telemetry"]["location"]["lat"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, generate models for your data. You can do it manually by creating classes or if you are in Visual Studio, this would be helpful:

Edit=> Paste Special=> Paste JSON as class. This will generate the classes for you.

Afterwords, go with Json.NET or any other library to parse your file:

```
public class Program{ 
      static void Main (string[] args){
      var client = new WebClient();
      var jsonString = client.DownloadString("Your link to Json file");
      var response= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject</*Json Class*/>(jsonString);
      //Now you can retrieve the data like this:
      var lat = response.details.telemetry.location.lat;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to import:

```
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```